# rails - load another page and replace the div

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

After some struggling, I managed to make the ajax work:

hello.js.erb:

```
$("#show_hosts").html("some text");
```

testQueuesController.rb:

```
class testQueuesController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @test_queues = testQueue.all

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html

      format.json { render json: @test_queues }

    end

  end

end
```

The relevant part in the view:

```
<%= link_to "hello", { :controller => "kashmir_queues", :action => "hello" }, :remote => true %>
```

Now, this is working, but what I really wanna do, is now load "some text", but to load another view I have named show_hosts.html.erb, how can I do it ?

Comment: your question is not clear , what do you mean by  "is now load "some text", but to load another view i have named show_hosts.html.erb"

Comment: I want to load a view called show_hosts.erb that will replace the div .. at the moment its hardcoded text that i put .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller add new action named hello

```
def hello
 queue = KashmirQueue.find(params[:id]) 
 @test_queues = testQueue.where(:host => queue.host) 
end
```

move your show.html.erb to a partial like _show.html.erb

then in hello.js.erb write

```
$("#show_hosts").html('#{escape_javascript(render "show.html.erb")}');
```

Comment: Almost work, but instead of showing show.html.erb, it shows me:
"escape_javascript(render "_show.html.erb")"
it doesnt calculate that line for some reason ..

Comment: Hmm, sorry, still prints the exact line :(

Comment: hello.js show contain this $("#show_hosts").html('#{escape_javascript(render "show.html.erb")}');

Comment: yes, it contains this line .. 
the link is : <%= link_to "hello", { :controller => "kashmir_queues", :action => "hello" }, :remote => true %>

the controller:
  def hello

   @test_queues = "blabla"

  end

the _show.html.erb is:
"BLABLABLA"

Comment: I tried to replace the line as you told .. still, hasnt changed from the previous line .. still prints that code line

Comment: i am not sure ..what's wrong ..with your code ..if you have done excatly what i had written in answer then it must work because ruby process anything writtem under #{} in string.

Comment: Ok, this line fixed it:
$("#show_hosts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'show.html.erb') %>");

10x!

Comment: well i use haml template that's why couldn't figure out ..this may be the issue ...anyways ..enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to render the view called `show_hosts.html.erb` in the HTML tag with the ID `show_hosts`.

To be able to do this you would need to create a partial for each host - something like `_host.html.erb` and write the following in `hello.js.erb`:

```
$('#show_hosts').html(<%= render partial: 'host', collection: @hosts %>)
```

Where `@hosts` is the name I assume you're using for the collection of hosts to be shown in `show_hosts.html.erb`, though I must admit I'm a bit confused because you use `@test_queues` in your controller.

For what it's worth (if I remember correctly) you also need to add `format.js` to your controller in order to render the `hello.js.erb` template.

Comment: The view that i want to load, show_hosts.html.erb, need to use this
queue = KashmirQueue.find(params[:id])
@test_queues = testQueue.where(:host => queue.host)

Comment: You need to set up all your instance variables before rendering the view, so this means that you need to create the `@test_queues` variable in the controller first. You still need to render the `show_hosts` as a partial, so I guess you could rename it `_show_hosts.html.erb` and change my line to: `$('#show_hosts').html(<%=j render partial: 'show_hosts', test_queues: @test_queues %>)`

Comment: and under what method in the controller should i setup up my variables ? and i didnt understand what you told about the format.js ..

Comment: for some reason, it doesnt work for me :( how the controller code should look like ?